# Paginationjs' Ajax call ignores text field value for filtering purposes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pagination

I am having a jQuery plugin called Paginationjs running. Underscore is also involved, but this is not what this post is about, actually.

I want to add a text filter, so the server can filter before sending the response. Here's the code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#pagination-container').pagination({
        dataSource: 'pagination/api',
        locator: 'data',
        totalNumberLocator: function(response) {
            // you can return totalNumber by analyzing response content
            return response.totalAmount;
        },
        alias: {
            pageNumber: 'pageNum',
            pageSize: 'limit'
        },
        pageSize: 5,
        ajax: {
            url : 'pagination/api',
            data: {
                filter : $('#filter').val()
            }
        },
        callback: function(data, pagination) {              
            var template = _.template($('#template-demo').html());
            var html = template({data: data});

            $('#data-container').html(html);
        }
    });
});
```

Whenever I change the page, the ajax call is fired, with the parameters filter, pageNum and limit attached to the url.

The filter value in that url stays the same during page changes: Empty. Even when I type things in that textfield with the ID "filter", it is still staying empty.

This plugin demands the setting called dataSource set, so I am forced to use the url there and also inside the ajax-setting called url.

Fun fact: When I have something entered in that text field and press F5 on Firefox, the browser keeps that content in that field after the refresh, and the entered value is sent to the server. The value for the url parameter "filter" is set then. But still, when I change the value and change pages, it's still the same value since the refresh of the site.

Is there any workaround to achieve this?

PS: I couldn't use the tag paginationjs because my reputation is below 1500.

Comment: I thing the value is not refreshed .in the chnage event ofthe text field stored the value in a hiden field and at calling time take the value from the hidden field

Comment: @LDS I just did, still no success

Answer (score 0):

So, since Paginationjs was initialising all the urls in the background with no possibility to change it the way as seen in my code above, here's a solution.

I added a button to re-initialize Paginationjs once it's clicked. This way, I don't need to use any Keypress-Event to send countless ajax requests to the server. I also changed the ID of the text field.

By re-initializing it, the filter value is getting attached with its value to the dataSource parameter. Ajax settings are not needed any longer.

```
$(function() {
    var paginationSettings = {
        dataSource: 'pagination/api',
        locator: 'data',
        pageSize: 5,
        totalNumberLocator: function(response) {
            return response.totalAmount;
        },
        alias: {
            pageNumber: 'pageNum',
            pageSize: 'limit'
        },
        callback: function(data, pagination) {              
            var template = _.template($('#template-demo').html());
            var html = template({data: data});

            $('#data-container').html(html);
        }
    }

    $('#pagination-container').pagination(paginationSettings);

    $('#filter-button').click(function() {
        paginationSettings.dataSource = 'pagination/api?filter=' + $('#filter-text').val();
        $('#pagination-container').pagination(paginationSettings);
    });
});
```